# Why PNotify option `after_open` doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, npm, pnotify

I finded [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067554/how-to-set-foucs-on-button-in-pnotify)

But property `after_open` doesn't work

I use `webpack` and `npm` [pnotify package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pnotify) with next code:

**entry.js**

```
'use strict';

let PNotify = require('pnotify');

PNotify.prototype.options.styling = 'bootstrap3';

(new PNotify({
  //...
  after_open(ui) {console.log('after_open');},
  //...
}));
```

Notification show, but without `after_open`

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using `callbacks` need include (extra pnotify module)

```
'use strict';

let PNotify = require('pnotify');
require('pnotify/dist/pnotify.callbacks.js');

/* next code */
```